# Display Linux boot messages on tty1 instead of ttyS1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, console, embedded-linux, tty

I'm working on an embedded Linux system with a display panel. The system is setup to output boot messages through the serial port on the system `/dev/ttyS1`. I'm trying to get these messages to show up on the display,`tty1`, and I'm looking for suggestions on how I go about doing this.

I tried changing the kernel command line from `console=ttyS1` to `console=tty1`; this has no effect.  Even with the change above boot messages are sent only to the serial port. I verified that the change to the kernel command line did take effect by querying `cat /proc/cmdline`

The last step of the boot process spawns `getty` to `tty1` and the login screen does appear on the panel. The panel itself is initialized much earlier in the boot sequence.

EDIT: @artless noise pointed out that sending the console to the virtual terminal requires a change in the kernel config. And indeed it does.  Follow the steps below to enable console output on virtual terminal

```
make menuconfig
```

and from the displayed GUI select the following

```
Device Drivers -> Character devices -> Support for console in virtual terminal
```

When invoking `make` you may need to provide additional options (ARCH, CROSS_COMPILE etc.) depending on the target you're building for.

Comment: Not all `tty` support a console.  Does yours?  Do you have it configured to support it (with Linux *.config*)?

Comment: You're right, it is a kernel configuration. For whatever reason I assumed this should just be a parameter on the kernel command line. Editing the question with the info you provided. Thanks much!

Comment: Where does this come from? `Device Drivers -> Character devices -> Support for console in virtual terminal`. This seems like a GUI thing, but you didn't mention what GUI you're using...

Comment: @tjameson: It's the linux kernel `make config` interface.

Comment: @tjameson added some additional info. hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Command line options can be provided either by the bootloader (e.g., u-boot *bootargs*) or hardcoded when configuring the kernel.

I know that on some older versions of the Linxu kernel, hard-coded options erroneously overwrote bootloader options.

So, have a look at the **.config** file and see if the wrong console has been set there.